# Как импортировать функцию из другой папки. Python

Tags: python, модули, импорт

Вот моя структура папок:

```
home/
    abc/
       world.py
    defg/
        lib.py
```

папка `abc` и папка `defg` находятся в паке `home`

Нужно импортировать функцию из файла `lib.py` в файл `world.py`, пробовала и через файл `__init__.py` и так:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/application/app/defg')

import lib
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from defg import lib
```

или

```
from defg.lib import my_lib
```

Comment: не получается, выходит ошибка Unable to import 'defg'pylint(import-error)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899436/pylint-unable-to-import-error-how-to-set-pythonpath Готовый ответ на SO